# Performing Python object introspection in a cmd.Cmd loop

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

My current project currently uses a `cmd.Cmd` instance as the main application interface. I cannot use my IDE to run the program at this point, and must use a batch file on my Windows.

This is making developing the next parts difficult. I need to be able to jump into the Python interpreter to examine my objects live.

Is there an easy way to do this? I haven't found any `cmd.Cmd` instances that expose Python this way.

Comment: I think you're looking for the [code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html) module. Why do you need a batch file to run a Python script?

Comment: I think I've run into a limitation of WinPython 3.5.1.1 and Sphinx and something else. I am not sure.  It involves relative imports. With them I can build the docs in Sphinx but cannot run the code as scripts in the IDE (Spyder) to get to the Python interpreter.

Comment: @eryksun, The code module is exactly what I was looking for. Can you post it as an answer so I can credit you?